# Ensuring a certain graphQL resolver runs last

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Is there a means to ensure that, during the resolution process, a certain resolver *always* gets run last?

My particular use case is that I'd like to optionally return some information to the client about the query that ran - this information is only available once all other resolvers have run, which is arbitrary depending on what users query.

Let's say my root resolver looks like this:

```
{    
  myQuery(args, context, info) {
    return this.dataLayer.load();
  }

  // This resolver must always be run last
  queryInfo(args, context, info) {
    return this.dataLayer.queryInfo();
  }
}
```

How can I always ensure that `queryInfo()` is run last?

Approaches considered:

- Including the data from `queryInfo()` in the data returned from `myQuery()`.  In this case, the data returned by queryInfo doesn't strictly belong to myQuery so it's less attractive semantically.
- Adding special request tracking code to `dataLayer`.  Has some timing weaknesses and is also more complicated than its worth.  If that's the only way we'll do without :).
- Manually tweaking the resolved data after GraphQL is done with it.  Effectively bypasses a really useful feature in GraphQL, would rather not.